# Href links for navigation bar

Tags: html, css, blogs, navbar

I just started learning HTML and decided I wanted to try to build a simple blog. I decided I wanted a navigation bar with links to other HTML files. I thought I had done this perfectly until I ran it and discovered that only the "Home" link works (which is the HTML file that I had put the href tags in) the other 4 links showed up as links but weren't clickable. All the files are located in the same folder.

```
<head>

<title>Music Project</title>

<link href="MusicProject.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div id="header">
    <h1 align="center" style="margin-top: -155px"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo" height="500" width="700" /></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="Music Project.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Artist.html">Artists</a></li>
<li><a href="album.html">Mixtapes/Albums</a></li>
<li><a href="suggestions.html">Suggestions</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</head>

#header {
    background-color: #888888;
    height:380px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

    }
body {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#main {
    overflow: auto;
}
#content {
    float:left;
}
#side {
    float:left;
}
#nav {
    height: 42px;
    background-color: #888888;
    }
#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    height:30px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
        }
#nav ul li {
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    width:246px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #00004B;
}
#nav ul li a {
    display: inline;
    width: 246px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.
Usually, you don't implement anchor links inside <head> tags, try to put it in  <body> tag and see if it works for you.

Comment: Adding what @choz has said, your image is covering the navigation links that you have, so you can't currently click them. Try to increase the height of the `#header` or remove it all together.

Comment: @choz Usually? How about never?

Comment: [validators](https://validator.nu) are your friend.

Answer (score -1):

As said you need to place your `<header>`, and `<content>` in the `<body>` tags.

This should help you out:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Music Project</title>
    <link href="MusicProject.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        #header {
            background-color: #888888;
            height: 380px;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #C0C0C0;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        #main {
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #content {
            float: left;
        }

        #side {
            float: left;
        }

        #nav {
            height: 42px;
            background-color: #888888;
        }

            #nav ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                height: 30px;
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
            }

                #nav ul li {
                    float: left;
                    margin: 10px;
                    width: 246px;
                    text-align: center;
                    font-family: "Arial";
                    font-size: 23px;
                    color: #00004B;
                }

                    #nav ul li a {
                        display: inline;
                        width: 246px;
                    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="header">
            <h1 style="margin-top: -155px; text-align:center;"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo" height="500" width="700" /></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Music Project.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Artist.html">Artists</a></li>
                <li><a href="album.html">Mixtapes/Albums</a></li>
                <li><a href="suggestions.html">Suggestions</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>


    <content>
         <!-- Page content here  -->
    </content>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cr8dLp5/2/)

Here is a link to help you learn the basics.  [Link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/designing-a-html-5-layout-from-scratch/)

Comment: Also check out this link to learn more. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/designing-a-html-5-layout-from-scratch/

Comment: No one should be using the transitional doctype for new web pages since 1999. meta and link tags do not have a closing slash. Your 'header' div serves no purpose and 'align' is deprecated and your h1 markup is invalid. Not to mention that there is no such thing as a content element.

Comment: You are correct, i will fix this. My mistake, i clicked on CS3 by mistake.